# HP Network Automation custom drivers

Tags: networking

I installed a demo for HP Network Automation last week and the network device I am trying to interface with is not listed in the "Supported Devices Matrix"
Apparently there is a way to design a custom driver, but so far all I have been able to find is an API guide. A quick search through the guide makes no mention of customer drivers for polling devices.
Does anyone have experience with HPNA custom drivers and If so what's my first step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download the NDS (Network Driver Studio) from HP, which includes an Eclipse plugin and complete documentation.

Comment: What are you up to these days, Les?  I worked at HP briefly while you were there.